# CURL POST: Ignore the response-body like it happens with FOLLOWLOCATION

Tags: php, curl

How can I not download request's body?

1. Using **CURLOPT_NOBODY** it performs **HEAD** request not sending POST data.
2. Uing **FOLLOWLOCATION=0** I make *request+body+request+body*.
3. Using **FOLLOWLOCATION=1** it makes *request+request+body* if it redirects to url I need.
4. If it redirects to the page I don't need I make *request+request+body+request+body*

I need: Request **ignoring** body + request with body.
Something like 3rd option but with redirect to url I really need (that obviously I can't control).

Comment: It doesn't know that it's going to get a redirect until AFTER it sends the body.

Comment: @CBroe I'm just not using it, like CURL on redirect. Why to download data that I don't need.

Comment: There's no way in the HTTP protocol to send a POST and tell the server not to send a body.

Comment: CURL knows how to ignore response body, if I get it right it doesn't download body (even if server sends it). Browsers do it the same way - Chrome's developer tools have «no response data available» for requests with 302 header.

Comment: _“Chrome's developer tools have «no response data available» for requests with 302 header.”_ – well that might be because there actually _was_ no HTTP Response Body. It still don’t see what this has to do with you POSTing something somewhere.

Comment: @CBroe I make POST request with credentials to authorize cookie session. This request redirects to another page that I don't need, and also a not redirected page has response with both 302 header and big body. I don't want neither to redirect nor to download its body.